# usable view size after status bar and navigation bar

Tags: ios, ipad

I am writing an iPad app that needs to know the usable area of the view for drawing purposes. The view is added into a Navigation controller, so I have the status bar plus the navigation controller both taking up a certain number of pixels. My app happens to be in landscape mode, although I don't think that's relevant.

I am able to get the correct view size AFTER rotation using didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation. But I can't figure out how to do it without the screen being rotated.

```
 - (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSLog(@"drfi %d %d", (int)self.view.frame.size.width, (int)self.view.frame.size.height);

}
```

^^ that works after rotation. Not before. Can't figure out how to get accurate numbers. And I REALLY don't want to hard wire this.

I will also need this function to be device independent -- it should work on the NEW iPad as well as the older iPad resolutions. I can handle the scaling issues once I know the exact usable area. Why is this so hard? Help!!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do it before rotation? Can you not simply redraw the view(s) in question after a rotate?

Comment: yes -- very simply there may never be a rotation!

Comment: Try to perform the calculation in viewDidAppear too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to specify your frame's view within the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation what i will suggest instead is setting some properties to your view autoresizing mask so that it automatically resize itself according to your view orientation.

By setting this for example to your view when your view is loaded (viewDidLoad method):

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

you specify that your view will change its width and height automatically and can get the right values you need to get from there.

You should read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW1
for a better understanding of views in iOS

**EDIT**

Also you probably want to spot what is the orientation of your device which can be accomplish with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];`

Comment: Alas... it does not work. The autoresizingMask setting will correctly account for the status bar (20 pixels) but does not account for the navigation bar.

Comment: Can you have access to the statusBar dimension and estimate the usable size of the area you are looking at from there? just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Your application looks like: there is a start up view, then in this view you will load and add a main view into window, right? Then you should do as below in your main view:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 20.0;
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: this is not getting the area correctly... the app first creates a navigation controller, then a table view controller inside that, then when the user chooses an option it pushes a UIView as a graphical drawing surface onto the navigationViewController. It's that final UIView which I can't get the right size for.

Comment: What did you do to "push" the "UIView" into NavigationController? do you mean "UIViewController"? you should place that graphical view into a ViewController, then push it into NavigationController using; [controller.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
CGRect navFrame = [[self.navigationController navigationBar] frame];
/* navFrame.origin.y is the status bar's height and navFrame.size.height is navigation bar's height.
So you can get usable view frame like this */
frame.size.height -= navFrame.origin.y + navFrame.size.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this dynamically by combining an instance method with a category method:

**Instance method:**

This assumes that your view controller (self) is embedded within a navigation controller.

```
-(int)getUsableFrameHeight {
  // get the current frame height not including the navigationBar or statusBar
  return [MenuViewController screenHeight] - [self.navigationController navigationBar].frame.size.height;
}
```

**Class category method:**

```
+(CGFloat)screenHeight {
    CGFloat screenHeight;
    // it is important to do this after presentModalViewController:animated:
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ||
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width;
    }
    return screenHeight;
}
```

The above will consistently give you the usable frame height after the status bar and navigation bar have been removed, in both portrait and landscape.

Note: the class method will automatically deduct the 20 pt for the status bar - then we just subtract the navigation header variable height (32 pt for landscape, 44 pt for portrait).